# How did the first microprocessors knew the meaning of binary codes?

Tags: cpu

I've been asking myself this question for more than one year and I just decided to ask the question on here. I don't know if it's the right place or not.

As far as I know microprocessors are a collection of transistors, But I don't understand some things about them: How did the inventor of microprocessors (or maybe computers) wrote the first code and programmed their IC? There were no other computers when they were making the first one.

Another thing I don't get is how an IC - especially the first IC which was actually a collection of transistors - knows what those codes mean? How does the IC understand what to do when the instruction says 1 or 0 or maybe 111011010101?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. This is a very broad question - on SU we like to stick to specific questions that have specific answers. It sounds like you want to read a history of computing. This is a huge subject! Try reading some of these [history of computing articles on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_history_of_computing_articles) to start you off.

Comment: There is hardware that converts binary codes into actual instructions.  The hardware I speak of is basically a huge multiplexer ( look  up how this IC works ).  In reality what happens is the proper instruction is decoded then the operation is performed.  The "CPU" makes this happen.

Answer (score 0):

When you write binary code, it is basically fed sequentially into the processor, to do part x or y or z.

Binary code is not constant across the machines, which is why you can't run your X-Box programs on the PS/3.  Like software, processors are being upgraded while keeping compatible with the previous versions: this is why you have intel 286/386/486/Pentiums etc.

One should not suppose that the binary code is interpret bitwise.  For example, one machine i worked on had a set of codes like 1ab "copy register a to b"  You would write for it a boot strap at a particular memory, and then do a system jump.  All of these are 8 bit codes, not 1-bit codes.

So in theory, an op-code is an electronic switch code for the chip: it opens and closes various paths, and lets the contents flow from A to B.  Others are interrupts, which tells the computer to do whatever it is primed to do (kind of like Go!).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you mean that those binary codes need to be interpreted too? So we're writing codes in High level programming languages and then those High levels are translated to binary codes and binary codes are translated to instructions that says when and which gate should be open for a voltage flow? And as I got from @Ramhound 's comment there is a huge multiplexer that gets 01s and opens or closes some gates! But I don't understand that how these ICs understand us even though there are just some transistors and other stuff which should not be able to understand.

Comment: At the most basic level, you can do things like arithmetic through binary logic (and, or, not), and store and recall.  Everything is built in layers on top of that.  The very first "computers" that were basically bread-boarded circuits were given each instruction of how to move bits to accomplish the most trivial tasks.  Each successive generation has incorporated building blocks to allow higher level tasks based on predefined smaller tasks.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know Microprocessors are a collection of transistors

Those transistors can be organized into **logic gates**, e.g. NAND, NOR and inverter gates.
Those gates can then used to build registers and logic circuits.
One of those circuits in a CPU is a functional block called the **instruction decoder**.
It's this instruction decoder that translates each machine code (what you are calling a binary code) into signals to perform the actual execution of that opcode.

> How did the inventor of Microprocessors (or maybe computers) wrote the first code and programmed their IC?

Why is your question about "microprocessors"?
Microprocessors are merely a subset of several types of digital computer processors.  Digital electronic computers have existed for a few decades prior to the first microprocessor.

Central to the concept of the modern computer is **memory** for the storage of (a) program in the form of machine code and (b) data.  (I'm conveniently ignoring HLL computers.)  A worst case scenario would use a **front panel** to manually enter the machine code into memory or use a preprogrammed memory, e.g. PROM or EPROM.

> Another thing I don't get is how an IC (specially the first IC which was actually a collection of transistors) knows what those codes mean?

An **IC** is simply an "integrated circuit". That circuit can be for analog as well as digital applications (or even mixed signal).  IC (aka "chip") and microprocessor are not synonymous terms.  A microprocessor is a digital (aka logic) IC.  But not every IC is a microprocessor.

> How does the IC understand what to do when the instruction says 1 or 0 or maybe 111011010101?

Assuming you are asking about a CPU, it's the **instruction decoder** that performs this function.  There are two primary techniques to implement this functionality: using hardwire or microprogramming.
Note that microprogramming has nothing to do with microprocessors.  The early microprocesors were hardwired (and did not have microprogramming).  The early microprogrammed computers were mainframe computers, such as the IBM S/360.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is: The designers of a processor first design the instruction set (the meanings of the various instruction codes, what operands are supported and how they're specified, etc.), and then build the processor by interconnecting logic gates so as to implement that instruction set.

If they'd wired it differently, the instruction set would be different.

Microprogrammed processors: At minimum, these some type of memory (there are several possibilities) as part of the interconnections that determine what the instruction set is. So by changing the contents of that memory (the "microcode"), one can change the instruction set. I said "at minimum" - it can get much more complicated.

If you want to learn more, I would suggest starting from the middle: Learn the assembly language for some machine. Preferably not x86/x64 as it's very complicated. I'd pick ARM if you want something  whose assembly language is relatively easy to learn, as well as relevant to current tech.

Then, if you want to know more, learn about logic circuits: AND, OR, NOT, NAND, NOR; then sequential circuits, starting with flip-flops, etc.

When you start thinking about how you'd build a full-fledged processor, or even something very simple like a PDP-8, out of these parts you will think "man, that's huge, and complicated." Well, it is huge. But it is not as complicated as you might first think. The complexity is mostly stacked in layers: Once you understand a low layer, you don't have to worry about its details any more, just what it does. Also, there is apparent complexity in repetition. A 32-bit adder has roughly 16 times as many gates as a 2-bit adder. But if you understand the 2-bit adder you can understand the 32-bit version. It's just more of what you've already seen.